# What is the meaning of the formulaic utterance 'savitassuva'? (and its variations)

Tags: sanskrit, meaning

> tāmasyai **savitassuva** iti

occurs in the Baudhayana Grihya Sutra.

> Deva **savita** pra**suva**

occurs in the *pariseshanam* (purification of food) mantra.

What is  the meaning of the phrase, though?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @cdr